# Placing n distinct varieties of identical objects into k distinct boxes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Say we have $n$ distinct varieties, with each variety containing $m_1, m_2, ... m_n$ identical objects. How many ways can we place these objects into $k$ distinct boxes?

Is it correct to place each variety individually, and multiply them together? That is, using the stars and bars method, $$\binom{m_1+k-1}{k-1} \times \binom{m_2+k-1}{k-1} \times ... \times \binom{m_n+k-1}{k-1}.$$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.